# Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x (1+e^{2x})(1+e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x=\log 2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

This integral popped up recently

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x (1+e^{2x})(1+e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x = \log 2$$

A solution using both real and complex analysis is welcome. I tried rewriting it using symmetry, and then the series expansion of $1/(1+e^{nx})$, however this did not quite make it.

\begin{align*}
I & = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x e^{3x}(1+e^{-2x})(1+e^{-x})}\mathrm{d}x \\
& = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-2x} -e^{-x}}{x} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n e^{-n x}\right)\left(\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^me^{-2mx}\right) \mathrm{d}x 
\end{align*}
The first part reminds me of a Frullani integral (it evaluates to $\log 2$). However I am unsure if this is the correct path, any help would be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One can start from the identity
$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-\mathrm e^x}{(1+\mathrm e^{2x})(1+\mathrm e^{x})}=\frac1{1+e^{x}}-\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{2x}}=-\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm du}\left(\frac1{1+\mathrm e^{ux}}\right)\cdot\mathrm du,
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-\mathrm e^x}{x(1+\mathrm e^{2x})(1+\mathrm e^{x})}=\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm e^{ux}}{(1+\mathrm e^{ux})^2}\mathrm du.
$$
Note that, for every nonzero $u$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm e^{ux}}{(1+\mathrm e^{ux})^2}\mathrm dx=\left.\frac{-1}{u(1+\mathrm e^{ux})}\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=\frac1{|u|},
$$
hence Fubini theorem shows that the integral to be computed is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm e^{2x}-\mathrm e^{x}}{x (1+\mathrm e^{2x})(1+\mathrm e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x =
\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm du}u=\log2.
$$
More generally, for every positive $a$ and $b$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm e^{ax}-\mathrm e^{bx}}{x (1+\mathrm e^{ax})(1+\mathrm e^{bx})}\mathrm{d}x = \log\left(\frac{a}b\right).
$$
This is rediscovering the fact that, for every monotonous function $\varphi$ with limits at $\pm\infty$,
$$
\int_\mathbb R\frac{\varphi(ax)-\varphi(bx)}x\mathrm dx=(\varphi(+\infty)-\varphi(-\infty))\cdot\log\left(\frac{b}a\right).
$$
in the present case for the function
$$
\varphi(x)=\frac1{1+\mathrm e^x}.
$$

Answer (score 20):

I reckon you are on the right track with Frullani's Integral, although the series expansion of the exponential function in the latter part of your derivation complicates matters unnecessarily.

Using a partial fraction decomposition and symmetry,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x (1+e^{2x})(1+e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}\right]\mathrm{d}x\\=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}\right]\mathrm{d}x$$
Setting $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$, we are in a position to use Frullani's integral as follows
$$I=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=2[f(0)-f(\infty)]\log\left(\frac{2}{1}\right)=2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\log 2=\log 2$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2x} -\expo{x}
     \over x\pars{1 + \expo{2x}}\pars{1 + \expo{x}}}\,\dd x=\ln\pars{2}:
     \ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2x} -\expo{x}
> \over x\pars{1 + \expo{2x}}\pars{1 + \expo{x}}}\,\dd x}
> =2\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\Lambda}{1 \over x}
> \pars{{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}} - {1 \over 1 + \expo{2x}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+} \atop \Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{\Lambda}{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{\epsilon}^{\Lambda}{1 \over 1 + \expo{2x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+} \atop \Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{\Lambda}{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{2\epsilon}^{2\Lambda}{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+} \atop \Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> +\int_{2\epsilon}^{2\Lambda}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{\Lambda}^{2\Lambda}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{2\epsilon}^{2\Lambda}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=2\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+} \atop \Lambda \to \infty}\bracks{%
> \half\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}{\dd x \over x}
> +\int_{\epsilon}^{2\epsilon}\pars{{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}} - \half}\,{\dd x \over x}
> -\int_{\Lambda}^{2\Lambda}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{2}
> -\half\
> \overbrace{\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}
> \int_{\epsilon/2}^{\epsilon}{\tanh\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ 0}}\
> -\
> \overbrace{\lim_{\Lambda \to \infty}
> \int_{\Lambda}^{2\Lambda}\!\!{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
> ^{\ds{=\ 0}}\,,
> \qquad\pars{~\large\tt\mbox{See below.}~}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{2x} -\expo{x}
     \over x\pars{1 + \expo{2x}}\pars{1 + \expo{x}}}\,\dd x=\ln\pars{2}}
$$

> $$
> {\tanh\pars{x} \over x} = \sech^{2}\pars{\xi} \leq 1\,,\qquad
> 0 < \xi < x
> $$
>   $$
> \verts{\int_{\epsilon/2}^{\epsilon}{\tanh\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
> <\half\,\epsilon\to 0\quad\mbox{when}\quad\epsilon\to 0^{+}
> $$

$$
\verts{\int_{\Lambda}^{2\Lambda}{1 \over 1 + \expo{x}}\,{\dd x \over x}}
<{1 \over \Lambda}\int_{\Lambda}^{2\Lambda}{\expo{-x} \over 1 + \expo{-x}}\,\dd x
={1 \over \Lambda}\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-\Lambda} \over 1 + \expo{-2\Lambda}}
\to 0\quad\mbox{when}\quad\Lambda\to\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x (1+e^{2x})(1+e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x &=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}\right]\mathrm{d}x\\&=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}\left[\frac{1}{1+e^x}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}\right]\mathrm{d}x\\&=2\lim_{s\to0^+}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}\ }{e^x+1}\mathrm dx-\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{2x}+1}\ \mathrm dx\end{align}$$

By letting $x\mapsto\frac12x$ in the last integral, we get

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{2x}+1}\ \mathrm dx=2^{-s}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\ \mathrm dx$$

Likewise, using the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function#Integral_representations), we have

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}\ }{e^x+1}\mathrm dx=\Gamma(s)\eta(s)$$

and so,

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2x}-e^x}{x (1+e^{2x})(1+e^{x})}\mathrm{d}x&=2\lim_{s\to0^+}(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(s)\eta(s)\\&=2\lim_{s\to0^+}\color{red}{\frac{1-2^{-s}}s}\color{blue}{s\Gamma(s)}\eta(s)\\&=2\color{red}{\ln(2)}\color{blue}{(1)}\eta(0)\\&=\ln(2)\end{align}$$